# Oracle SQL - Select date between month-current year(-1) to month-current year

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a column with a date in it as well as other columns in the table. I want to be able to:

show all rows that match the date of having September 1st of the previous year to July 30th of the current year.

I know some of what needs to be done just not sure on the specific syntax of the dates..

```
SELECT * FROM xx
WHERE ASM_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-1,'YY') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YY');
```

That's what I have so far..

I know I can use SYSDATE and 'YYYY' to get the current year and then do that -1 for the previous year, I'm unsure how to specify the months in addition to that however.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  xxx
WHERE
      ASM_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), -12)
  AND ASM_DATE <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'),   1)
```

Comment: Great that this query works, although it isn't an answer to "show all rows that match the date of having September 1st of the previous yr to July 30th of the current year."

Comment: No but it was enough for me to figure it out based on those :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look a the oracle ADD_MONTHS function.

There's a complete listing of datetime functions in the [oracle reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Say, current month is **April of 2015**.

One year data to previous month (from **01-FEB-2014** to **31-MAR-2015**):

```
SELECT *
FROM xx
WHERE 
ASM_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -14) 
AND
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1))
```

One year data including current month (from **01-MAR-2014** to **30-APR-2015**):

```
SELECT *
FROM xx
WHERE 
ASM_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -13) 
AND
LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'))
```